# Create a vector of strings with index

Tags: r

Is there any quick methods to create a vector of strings like :

```
c("a1","b2","c3","d5"...)
```

I only know how to do it with loops.

Answer (score 4):

We can try:

```
paste0(letters, 1:26)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way using [purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) :-)

```
# create numbers [1-10]
numbers <- 1:10

purrr::map_chr(numbers,~paste0("X",.x))

# Output
>  [1] "X1"  "X2"  "X3"  "X4"  "X5"  "X6"  "X7"  "X8"  "X9"  "X10"
```

Combine two vectors

```
# use ascii code for lowercase chars [a-j] see https://www.ascii-code.com/ 
characters <- R.oo::intToChar(97:106)

purrr::map2_chr(characters, numbers, ~paste0(.x,.y))

# Output
> [1] "a1"  "b2"  "c3"  "d4"  "e5"  "f6"  "g7"  "h8"  "i9"  "j10"
```